# How to convert convert.c into exe file and make it run?

Tags: libsvm

I need to convert a CSV file into a libsvm format. I want to use convert.c 
I dont know how to use it.

Can somebody give the steps in using it.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what libsvm is, but to use a .c file (a C or possibly C++ source code file) you will need a [C or C++ compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_compilers#C_compilers).

I would suggest reading the documentation for the library you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know, how to compile a C-file but have to use/learn SVM I'd suggest to start with a software, where you can learn ML/SVM without programming.

E.g.: RapidMiner, Weka, Orange, KNime. Whey all provide a possibility to load CSV and use it with libsvm.

Search on SO or in google for "csv to libsvm" You'l find some ready to use tools.

If it still has to be C, download [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) and build the exe from your C-File.